# pythonのモックオブジェクトのコンストラクタでname属性を設定する方法ありますか。

Tags: python

属性にidとnameを持ったモックオブジェクトを作成したいのですが、下記のようにコンストラクタに`name=`を指定するとモックのreprとして使われるため、name属性としてはアクセスできません。

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock
>>> m = MagicMock(id=11, name='mock_name')
>>> m.id
11
>>> m.name
<MagicMock name='mock_name.name' id='139722341173472'>
>>>
```

下記のようにモックを作成したあとでname属性を設定すれば、期待通りの動きをするのですが、コンストラクタでname属性を指定する方法があるでしょうか。

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock
>>> m = MagicMock(id=123)
>>> m.name = 'mock_name'
>>> m.id
123
>>> m.name
'mock_name'
>>>
```

Comment: 公式ドキュメントの[Mock の名前と name 属性](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-names-and-the-name-attribute)に`"name" は Mock コンストラクタの引数なので、モックオブジェクトが "name" 属性を持つことを望む場合、単に生成時にそれを渡すことはできません。`と明記されていますので、コンストラクタでname属性の指定はできないように見えます。

Comment: ありがとうございました。公式ドキュメントの記載通りにインスタンス化したあと、name属性を設定します。